# Not using HTML forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a scenario, and I was thinking if this approach is acceptable?

Instead of using html form, I most of the time omit creating one and instead do the sending of the form information in the form of jquery stuff say $.ajax;

Thus this have no security issues, performance issues, semantics irregularities or whatsoever?

Can this approach bypass the standard form of coding an html form? why use forms when we can send its content using javascript or the like?

Thanks,

Comment: what if js disable..js should be mostly used for user experience. ?

Comment: Worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063392/is-there-any-advantage-for-dynamic-website-like-this-rather-than-pure-ajax-based

Answer (score 2):

You would still need an HTML form. But I'm guessing you mean you wish to create a page/site with limited whole-page regular HTTP postback?

There is nothing that wrong with your idea, however you should consider the case of users who have javascript turned off in their browsers or those who are using older browsers.

Think of Gmail for example - it is available in pure Ajax form and also with old-fashioned Http functionality as a fall-back for older browsers.

Comment: You would still need a HTML document you odn't need a `<form />` (as long as JS is enabled or you don't care about those where it's disabled)

Comment: I think I meant to say 'you'd still need HTML form controls'. You're right, you don't need a `<form>`.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your security question:

It's as secure as submitting a form since it's basically the same action (opening a web site). The only difference is it happens asynchronously "in the background".

Answer (score -2):

The HTML form enables the user to enter data (select from a list, enter text etc).

So please demonstrate how to do this without an HTML form,

Comment: You can't enter anything in a `<form />`you do that in `<input />`, `<textarea />` and the like

Comment: An HTML form collects all those inputs together. That was my understanding. So why the user presses the submit button it is collected together and can be used for GET or POST.

Comment: or you have a (click) event handler that collects the data and sends the request to the server

Comment: @RuneFS - Easier to contain all the inputs in one `<form>` element. Easier for JS to collate (or use the `onSubmit` event to collect data) or even if JS is disabled will also work.

Comment: It's not easier for JS to collect the data in a form compared to collecting them in on div. Sure the submit button won't work (which I implicitly stated ie. ignoring JS disabled). However Your challenge that it can be done. I'm simply stating is rather easy to do it (as long as JS is enabled)

Comment: How about `var form = document.getElementById("myform")` them `var elements = form.elements`. This returns an array of the `input` elements etc in that form. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18629/discussion-between-rune-fs-and-ed-heal)